# How to get a date that now date minus condition value?

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date picker, i want to user cannot pick a date but date now minus this date less than 18 year(i don't want the user less than 18 years old).but i don't know how to do that.

i described my idea by this code below.

```
    const nowDate = new Date()
    const valueCondition = 18
    const dateWishes = nowDate - valueCondition
```

how can i do that?

have a nice day, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Use [getFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear)

```js
const nowDate = new Date();
const valueCondition = 18;
const dateWishes = nowDate.getFullYear() - valueCondition; // 2021 - 18
console.log(dateWishes); // 2003
```

Comment: This method will exclude a great many dates that are between 17 and 18 years ago.